# Unity Multiplayer Server Client desync due to rotation from mouse input

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, multiplayer

I am currently working on implementing my first multiplayer system with server authority and client side prediction with server reconciliation. But I am running into a problem that I just don't know how other's have solved. I've implemented a fixed timestep system according to a tutorial I found: https://github.com/Ajackster/ClientPredictionTutorial/blob/master/Assets/Scripts/Client.cs and in each timestep I process user keypresses and change the velocity accordingly. Which works great until I start changing my rotation with mouse input. User input and mouse input are read in the Update() function which I think is the source of my desync problems. My client is changing its rotation with each frame. but the server is only changing its input when it receives the rotation from the client in the fixed timestep "handleTick()" method. I believe this is causing a desync in the velocity of my client object and the velocity of the server object. because the velocity of my client is updating with each render (potentially, if we are receiving new mouse input in each update frame) but the velocity of my server only changes in the fixed time step call which could be called less frequently or more frequently than update()

I hope this makes some sense to you brilliant people out there. Is there anyway to handle this?? Please excuse this trash code but this is a snippet from my project

```
void Update()
    {
        timer += Time.deltaTime;
        

        if (!isServer)
        {
            verticalAxisInput = 0;
            horizonalAxisInput = 0;
            if (inputManager.getKeyManager().getKey("w"))
            {
                verticalAxisInput = 1;
            }
            else if (inputManager.getKeyManager().getKey("s"))
            {
                verticalAxisInput = -1;
            }
            
            if (inputManager.getKeyManager().getKey("d"))
            {
                horizonalAxisInput = 1;
            }
            if (inputManager.getKeyManager().getKey("a"))
            {
                horizonalAxisInput = -1;
            }
EDIT: The below line was the source of the bug. needs to be moved after transform.localRotation update
            playerInput = (transform.forward * verticalAxisInput) + (transform.right * horizonalAxisInput);
            
            pressJump = inputManager.getSingleKeyInput("space") > 0;
            pressSprint = inputManager.getSingleKeyInput("left shift") > 0;
            mouseX = Input.GetAxis(InputKeys.MOUSE_X_AXIS);
            mouseY = Input.GetAxis(InputKeys.MOUSE_Y_AXIS);
            
            playerCam.transform.localRotation = lookY(mouseY);
            transform.localRotation = lookX(mouseX);
        }

        while (timer >= MIN_TIME_BETWEEN_TICKS)
        {
            timer -= MIN_TIME_BETWEEN_TICKS;

            handleTick();
            currentTick++;
        }  


private void handleTick()
    {
        if (isServer)
        {
            PlayerInputPacket packet = RemoteDataConnection.instance.getData();
            pressJump = inputManager.getSingleKeyInput("space") > 0;
            transform.localRotation = packet.playerRot;
            inputManager.getKeyManager().setKeyMap(packet.keyMap);
            
            verticalAxisInput = 0;
            horizonalAxisInput = 0;
            if (inputManager.getKeyManager().getKey("w"))
            {
                verticalAxisInput = 1;
            }
            else if (inputManager.getKeyManager().getKey("s"))
            {
                verticalAxisInput = -1;
            }
            
            if (inputManager.getKeyManager().getKey("d"))
            {
                horizonalAxisInput = 1;
            }
            if (inputManager.getKeyManager().getKey("a"))
            {
                horizonalAxisInput = -1;
            }
         
            playerInput = (transform.forward * verticalAxisInput) + (transform.right * horizonalAxisInput);
        }
        else
        {
            ClientDataConnection.instance.writeData(new PlayerInputPacket(inputManager.getKeyManager().getKeyMap(), transform.localRotation));
        }
        
        if (currentJumpCoolDown > 0)
        {
            currentJumpCoolDown--;
        }



        move(playerInput, pressJump, pressSprint);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem. The client was calculating input velocity in the update() loop but the server was doing that in the fixed timestep tick method. when made the client calculate this in the fixed timestep method my problem was fixed. I don't entirely understand how this fixes the problem because when the client was processing input it was also sending the server its rotation value so I thought the server and client would get the same result but that must of not of been the case. if anyone understands why this is I would really appreciate an answer

```
    playerInput = (transform.forward * verticalAxisInput) + (transform.right * horizonalAxisInput);
    move(playerInput, pressJump, pressSprint);
```

full code after fix:

```
        void Update()
    {
        timer += Time.deltaTime;
        

        if (!isServer)
        {
            verticalAxisInput = 0;
            horizonalAxisInput = 0;
            if (inputManager.getKeyManager().getKey("w"))
            {
                verticalAxisInput = 1;
            }
            else if (inputManager.getKeyManager().getKey("s"))
            {
                verticalAxisInput = -1;
            }
            
            if (inputManager.getKeyManager().getKey("d"))
            {
                horizonalAxisInput = 1;
            }
            if (inputManager.getKeyManager().getKey("a"))
            {
                horizonalAxisInput = -1;
            }

            pressJump = inputManager.getSingleKeyInput("space") > 0;
            pressSprint = inputManager.getSingleKeyInput("left shift") > 0;
            mouseX = Input.GetAxis(InputKeys.MOUSE_X_AXIS);
            mouseY = Input.GetAxis(InputKeys.MOUSE_Y_AXIS);
            
            playerCam.transform.localRotation = lookY(mouseY);
            transform.localRotation = lookX(mouseX);
            Debug.Log(characterController.velocity);
        }

        while (timer >= MIN_TIME_BETWEEN_TICKS)
        {
            timer -= MIN_TIME_BETWEEN_TICKS;

            handleTick();
            currentTick++;
        }


        doWeaponBounce();
    }

    private void handleTick()
    {
        if (isServer)
        {
            PlayerInputPacket packet = RemoteDataConnection.instance.getData();
            pressJump = inputManager.getSingleKeyInput("space") > 0;
            transform.localRotation = packet.playerRot;
            inputManager.getKeyManager().setKeyMap(packet.keyMap);
            
            verticalAxisInput = 0;
            horizonalAxisInput = 0;
            if (inputManager.getKeyManager().getKey("w"))
            {
                verticalAxisInput = 1;
            }
            else if (inputManager.getKeyManager().getKey("s"))
            {
                verticalAxisInput = -1;
            }
            
            if (inputManager.getKeyManager().getKey("d"))
            {
                horizonalAxisInput = 1;
            }
            if (inputManager.getKeyManager().getKey("a"))
            {
                horizonalAxisInput = -1;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            ClientDataConnection.instance.writeData(new PlayerInputPacket(inputManager.getKeyManager().getKeyMap(), transform.localRotation));
        }
        
        if (currentJumpCoolDown > 0)
        {
            currentJumpCoolDown--;
        }


        playerInput = (transform.forward * verticalAxisInput) + (transform.right * horizonalAxisInput);
        move(playerInput, pressJump, pressSprint);
    }
```

Comment: While the above code does fix the problem it is actually hiding the original bug. the client code was calculating the input velocity before updating the rotation from new mouse input. While the server was updating the input velocity after receving the new mouse input. Dumb bug I should of seen earlier but the original code will work if I move the playerInput = ... after the rotation update